# Calculate number of elements on the specific criteria

Tags: php, php-5.3, php-5.6

I have an array like

```
array(3) { 
  [0]=> array(2) { 
    ["AllotmentId"]=> string(36) "6b594c22-73f1-0a2a-298c-2d3feba2905d" 
    ["RoomId"]=> string(36) "9a21e427-16fd-7a9e-bc16-537dc55093bb" } 
  [1]=> array(2) { 
    ["AllotmentId"]=> string(36) "99730f9a-2242-24bd-0908-b9035a75d328" 
    ["RoomId"]=> string(36) "9a21e427-16fd-7a9e-bc16-537dc55093bb" } 
  [2]=> array(2) { 
    ["AllotmentId"]=> string(36) "fft54c22-73f1-0a2a-2558c-2d3fgged" 
    ["RoomId"]=> string(36) "663ghjytf-16fd-7a9e-bc16-537dc55r5g0" } 
}
```

Now I want to create another array which will store the following information like

```
[ 
  RoomId => "9a21e427-16fd-7a9e-bc16-537dc55093bb",  NumberOfAllotments => 2 
  RoomId => "663ghjytf-16fd-7a9e-bc16-537dc55r5g0",  NumberOfAllotments => 1
]
```

It should calculate the number of allotment ids against room ids and create another array.

I am not able to tweak the below lines of code.

```
foreach ($allotmentArray as $key => $allotment) 
{          
    $arrayToPush = array('RoomId' => $allotment["RoomId"], "NumberOfAllotments" => $count]);
    array_push($freeRooms, $arrayToPush); 
}
```

Please help !!!

Comment: Do you mean `[ 
  RoomId => "9a21e427-16fd-7a9e-bc16-537dc55093bb",  NumberOfAllotments => 2 

  RoomId => "663ghjytf-16fd-7a9e-bc16-537dc55r5g0",  NumberOfAllotments => 1
]` OR `[ 
 [ RoomId => "9a21e427-16fd-7a9e-bc16-537dc55093bb",  NumberOfAllotments => 2], 

[  RoomId => "663ghjytf-16fd-7a9e-bc16-537dc55r5g0",  NumberOfAllotments => 1]
]`

Comment: I want to get the number of allotments done per room which are stored in an array the above question. like room id "9a21e427-16fd-7a9e-bc16-537dc55093bb" has two allotments ids like "6b594c22-73f1-0a2a-298c-2d3feba2905d",  "99730f9a-2242-24bd-0908-b9035a75d328" so the numberOfAllotments will be 2 for this roomid and the put them in seperate array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
// Your array
$array = array(
  0 => array(
    "AllotmentId" => "6b594c22-73f1-0a2a-298c-2d3feba2905d",
    "RoomId" => "9a21e427-16fd-7a9e-bc16-537dc55093bb" ),
  1=> array(
    "AllotmentId"=> "99730f9a-2242-24bd-0908-b9035a75d328",
    "RoomId" => "9a21e427-16fd-7a9e-bc16-537dc55093bb" ),
  2=> array(
    "AllotmentId"=> "fft54c22-73f1-0a2a-2558c-2d3fgged",
    "RoomId"=> "663ghjytf-16fd-7a9e-bc16-537dc55r5g0" )
);
```

1/ I create a temp array

```
$temp_array = array();
```

2/ Then I add all roomId value in this temp array

```
foreach ($array as $key => $data) {
    $temp_array[] = $data['RoomId'];
}
```

3/ Now I count the number of each roomId

```
$temp_result = array_count_values($temp_array);
```

Here the output is :

```
array (size=2)
  '9a21e427-16fd-7a9e-bc16-537dc55093bb' => int 2
  '663ghjytf-16fd-7a9e-bc16-537dc55r5g0' => int 1
```

4/ Now I will build my result array

```
$result = array();
```

5/ I add a new array with the roomId and the number of allotments

```
foreach ($temp_result as $roomId => $NumberOfAllotments) {
    $result[] = array(
        'RoomId' => $roomId,
        'NumberOfAllotments' => $NumberOfAllotments
    );
}
```

Here is the output :

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'RoomId' => string '9a21e427-16fd-7a9e-bc16-537dc55093bb' (length=36)
      'NumberOfAllotments' => int 2
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'RoomId' => string '663ghjytf-16fd-7a9e-bc16-537dc55r5g0' (length=36)
      'NumberOfAllotments' => int 1
```

Is it what you are looking for?

I think you can find an other way using some php array function, but this method works (if I understand what you wanted !)

Comment: I want to get the number of allotments done per room which are stored in an array the above question. like room id "9a21e427-16fd-7a9e-bc16-537dc55093bb" has two allotments ids like "6b594c22-73f1-0a2a-298c-2d3feba2905d",  "99730f9a-2242-24bd-0908-b9035a75d328" so the numberOfAllotments will be 2 for this roomid

Comment: @NidaAmin Yes, it's what I did no? I build an array with one result for each RoomId and the number of allotments of this roomId, where is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

try this code:

first count and save in a key value array which is named $targetArray.
then generate you prefered output in $outputArray:

```
<?php

$targetArray = array();

foreach ($allotmentArray as $allotment) 
{
    if(!array_key_exists($allotment['RoomId'], $targetArray))
        $targetArray[$allotment['RoomId']] = 0;
    $targetArray[$allotment['RoomId']]++;
}

$outputArray = array();

foreach($targetArray as $RoomId=> $count)
    $outputArray[] = array('RoomId'=>,'count'=>$count);

var_dump($outputArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

As I see it you don't need to loop.
Use array_column and array_count_values.

```
$Roomid = array_count_values(array_column($arr, "RoomId"));
```

Now Roomid key is the Roomid and the value is the count of each.

If you must have the array as in your question you can do like this:

```
$Roomid = array_count_values(array_column($arr, "RoomId"));
Foreach($Roomid as $room => $count){
    $arr[] = ["Roomid" => $room, 'NumberOfAllotments' => $count];
}
```

This will only loop each unique room, instead of the full array.

Output(s):
https://3v4l.org/ohUJS